# Javascript order of execution: how to detect object creation

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

I want to instantiate a new MediaElementPlayer object. When it's successfully created, I want to pass the whole object on to another function (my_object.attachEvents). My code is as follows:

```
var options = {
   success: function () {
       //point 2
       console.log("passing player object", local_player_instance);
       my_main_object.attachEvents(local_player_instance);          
   }
}

//point 1
console.log('player inited', local_player_instance);
local_player_instance.video = new MediaElementPlayer('#video_player', options);

my_main_object.attachEvents = function(local_player_instance) { 
    local_player_instance.video.play()  
}
```

In Firefox, the assignment at point one is executed before the line at point 2 calls the attach events method.

Im Chrome, point 2 is evaluate first, and as a result when the play method in the attach events function is called it doesn't exist.

My question is, how do I pass successfully pass the MediaElementPlayer to another function when it is created?

Comment: is it inside `DOMReady` event?

Comment: Like $(document).ready() ? It's in a jQuery widget, so I guess so. By this point, successful calls to the dom have already been made.

Comment: Does the `success` function not have a parameter for the instance?

Comment: No, it returns the DOM element but not whole object...

Comment: I think the problem is not in code you show. There is no way that `point 2` would be executed first if you are not invoking `options.success` somewhere between creating options object and `point 1`. Code you have shown seems to be valid.

Comment: I think I might raise an issue on the github page and link to this

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this in a cross browser way is

```
// here's where you'll store a global reference to the player
var globalMediaElement = null;
var options = {
   success: function (domNode, mediaElement) {
       globalMediaElement = mediaElement;

       doStuff();


       // you can also get the the player via jQuery here
       $('#video_player').player
   }
}

// create MediaElement
new MediaElementPlayer('#video_player', options);

function doStuff() {
     globalMediaElement.play();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this, but I am completely sure neither of these works. Long after the video has been inited  $('#video_player').player is set to undefined. domNode and  mediaElement are both set to the dom node. Is this because I'm using old jQuery?

Comment: I'm really going insane now... the whole codebase can be seen here, in case it's of any help...https://github.com/jimmytidey/talking_jobs_skinned

Comment: Hi @john-dyer, I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, because $('#video_player').player is definitely not set for me?